# How to change the text of a label after UITableViewCell re-order

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom cells.  When I tap on edit, the TableView goes into edit mode as it should.  I can move the cells around, and delete them, and save the results to Core Data Entities.  The new order of cells is retained in Core Data, that all works.

However I would like to have the new position of the cell reflected, either after a move, or after tapping 'Done'.  The value in the label is always going to be the row + 1, regardless of where they are moved.  How do I re-refence

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

-Paul

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
ProfileItems *profileItems = [ingredients objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
// NSLog(@"profileItems: %@", profileItems);

[ingredients removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
[ingredients insertObject:profileItems atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

NSInteger start = fromIndexPath.row;
NSLog(@"start: %d", start);

NSInteger end = toIndexPath.row;
NSLog(@"end: %d", end);

// Update Core Data to reflect the cell's new position in the TableView
profileItems.profileItemsSongOrder = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:end + 1];

// This won't work becuase there is no cell referenced in here.  Do I have to point to it again? If so how?
cell.profileItemsSongNumberLabel.text   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",profileItems.profileItemsSongOrder]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with the following for...loop

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) 
    {
        [[profileItemsNSMArray objectAtIndex:i] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i + 1] forKey:@"profileItemsSongOrder"];
    }
```